# C# Single line if with void return

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I'm looking to use a single line if statement with the `?` operator to call return on a void method.

This is the full form statement:

```
if (failPaths.Count == paths.Count) {
    return;
}
```

I'm aware that I could do something like `if (failPaths.Count == paths.Count) return;` but I was just interested in seeing how it would be done with the `?` operator.

Comment: You can't. They are not the same. One is a statement; the other is an expression.

Comment: The conditional operator is not a replacement for the `if`. It's just a shortcut to get a value according to a conditon and should be used only if it improves readability. An `if`-statement is more powerful and should be used for flow control and if the conditional operator would be too cumbersome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can't be done using [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) mentioned by you as `?` operator.

In fact, conditional operator just evaluates condition and return either first or secod from two expressions - so it can be considered as expression itself.

But in your example `if` statement is used not for **expression evaluation**, but for **control flow**.

Answer (score 3):

In C# there's no way to do what you want to achieve.

Ternary operator requires that both `true` and `false` values evaluates to the type of the left side of the assignment expression (or method/property return value).

Since there's no explicit way of returning/setting `void`, there's no way to have this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to say the "? : " operator.

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that, cause the compiler expect "else" condition.

```
(condition)?true:else
```